# Antenna House xsl error

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, antenna-house

We are using Antenna House xsl formatter.
xml and xsl files are located at the server accessible to both of us with equal permissions settings.
We connect with remote desktop to server machine.  My co-worker has everything working fine.

I get a weired error:
Error is:

```
9185(2003) FO Transformation is failed
Keyword xsl:script may not be used in namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform

Error occurred during compilation of included or imported stylesheet 
  'file:///C:/folder/subfilder/lib_someXSLIncludedInTheOneI_Use.xsl'
```

Again, when I connect with remote desktop from my user to server machine - I get error.
My co-worker goes to the same server and all is formatted fine.
Heelp !!! Please !!!

Comment: I think it will help if you show us the XSL code around where it says "xsl:script" in your `lib_someXSLIncludedInTheOneI_Use.xsl`.

Comment: Yes. My comment was meant to be an invitation to Dima. Clarifying now...

Comment: Thanks.  I never knew how to do this.  I was treating this site, as a questions/answers forum, and didn't realize it has functional aspect it.  Is it the little arrows up and down near the messages?

Comment: There should be a check mark (tick mark) near the up/down arrows. Click that to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you.  I found how to mediate the problem.  However, I still do not know why it doesn't under my login but does under some one else's.
What I did, was that I found there are settings under Format Settings -> XSLT Settings.
I had to provide expernal path to saxon.jar and to XML Transformer.jar

Default option was to use MSXML MSXML3, and it didn't work for me.
When I provided this

```
java -cp "C:/libs/saxon/saxon.jar;C:\libs\XMLTransformer.jar" com.icl.saxon.StyleSheet -o %3 %1 %2
```

it started working

Comment: The data for Format Settings -> XSLT Settings is stored in a file, which is stored in Users/you/Appdata/Roaming/Antennahouse/... That's why this behavior is user specific.

Answer (score 1):

What version of XSLT does your version of Antenna House XSL formatter support? What version of XSLT does your stylesheet claim to be (see the version= attribute.)?

`xsl:script` is part of the proposed XSLT 1.1 draft that never made it to the end of the W3C approval process. It seems likely that Antenna House XSL formatter doesn't support it... or perhaps doesn't support the particular script language that stylesheet uses (e.g. javascript).

That wouldn't in itself explain the fact that your coworker sees no problem, but it might shed light on the answer. If the XSL stylesheet *shouldn't* be working with the XSL processor you're using, then the weirdness is not with you, but rather I would look for evidence that you and your coworker might be inadvertently running different processors or different stylesheets.

Comment: Thank you.  I found how to mediate the problem.  However, I still do not know why it doesn't under my login but does under some one else's.

Comment: @Dima: maybe you have an environment variable setting for CLASSPATH that is just for your user; or maybe your colleague does.